Propagating useState change from child component fails to close Popup
I understand that the proper way to propagate changes from a child to a parent is to pass the parent's change handling function to the child.
In this instance I have done that but the child is not updating a closeHandler to hide a popup. The popup stays open so I'm not sure what I missed. This code actually works fine in a different project implementation.
I just can't see what I'm missing in this implementation, I could use some more experienced eyes to help me debug this.
The parent component InventoryDetails.jsx:
import './InventoryDetails.css'
import { dbFormatTime } from '../../services/utilities'
import InventoryDataPopup from './InventoryDataPopup'
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

const InventoryDetails = ({details}) => {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  recordTime = dbFormatTime(details.data_entry_date)

  const handleClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
    console.log(open)
  }

  function openPopup() {
    setOpen(true);
  }


  return (
    <div className="inventory-detail" onClick={openPopup}>
      <span className="inventory-name">{details.invoice_name}</span><span className="inventory-size">{quantity}</span>
      <div><InventoryDataPopup handleClose={handleClose} open={open} data={details} /></div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default InventoryDetails;

The immediate child InventoryDataPopup.jsx:
import './InventoryDataPopup.css'
import Dialog from '@mui/material/Dialog';
import DialogTitle from '@mui/material/DialogTitle';
import DialogContent from '@mui/material/DialogContent';
import DialogActions from '@mui/material/DialogActions';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import InventoryInfo from './InventoryInfo';

const InventoryDataPopup = (props) => {

  return (
    <div>
      <Dialog open={props.open}>
        <DialogTitle>Inventory Info</DialogTitle>
        <DialogContent>
          <InventoryInfo data={props.data} />
        </DialogContent>
        <DialogActions>
          <Button onClick={props.handleClose}>Close</Button>
        </DialogActions>
      </Dialog>
    </div>
  )
}

export default InventoryDataPopup;

The console.log in handleClose shows that setOpen(false) is not updating.
Not sure how this is failing.

I see no issue in your code and it works copy/pasted into this running sandbox. Are there any errors on your end? Can you [edit] to include a complete [mcve]? If possible, see if you can also create a running sandbox demo that reproduces the problem that we could inspect live.

Ok. Thanks for checking it Drew. I'll work out a sandbox example and set if I can reproduce the problem.
